# re-call variable attached function from another function

Tags: jquery, function, variables

Sorry if my question title is somewhat confusing, but I have no idea on how to ask this question in a single sentence...

I have this code:

```
clientInformation = (function() {
//var priser = null;
$.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'cache': false,
        'url': stepp+'json/dataFile.json?ver='+Math.random(),
        'dataType': "json",
    'success': function(data) {
            clientInformation = data;
        //console.log('client collected',data);
    }
    });
    return clientInformation;
})();
```

Which runs on page load.
IF there's a change in the dataFile.json I would like to reload the above script.

I would expect that If I type:

```
clientInformation()
```

the function would fire again, but...
All I get is: "clientInformation is not a function".

I have tried:

```
clientInformation
clientInformation.call()
```

How can I re-call the above function without having to rewrite or create a separate function to do the same job over again ?

Comment: In the success callback you destroy the function with this... `clientInformation = data;`  Change that variable name to something else and your problem will go away.

Comment: sorry, no. that did not help at all. I still get "Uncaught TypeError: clientInformation is not a function"

Comment: Actually, I did miss something else.  You're executing it immediately.  Just change it to `var clientInformation = function() { ... }` with no brackets around it or after it.  The ones after it are causing it to be executed immediately, so `clientInformation` becomes the result.  Also get rid of the return.  You're setting it to a function so you don't need to return the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of minor things that would stop your code working.

First of all, you're executing the function immediately, and then setting the return value to the variable `clientInformation`.  That can be fixed by removing the brackets after the function (and the ones wrapping it are not required either).

Secondly, you're assigning the result of the Ajax call to `clientInformation`, so even if the first issue was resolved then you'd overwrite the function with the result.  Next time you try to call it you'd be trying to execute the result - the function no longer exists.  You could change the variable name, or pass the result in a callback.

Also, using `async: false` is a bad idea.  This locks all execution until the call returns.  This may not be noticeable but it could just as easily make the website hang indefinitely for some users.  It's much better to remove that and use a callback, as previously mentioned.

Here's an example of using a callback, which I'd strongly recommend over using a synchronous Ajax call and a global variable for the results...

```
function clientInformation(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        'global': false,
        'cache': false,
        'url': stepp + 'json/dataFile.json?ver=' + Math.random(),
        'dataType': 'json',
        'success': function(data) {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Then, to call the function and handle the response, you would do something like this...

```
clientInformation(function(data) {
    console.log(data);  // do whatever you need with the response data here
});
```

The callback may be overkill, but it depends on the situation.  If you *always* do the same thing when the Ajax call is successful then you're just as well putting the code in the success handler and removing the callback parameter.

Comment: No worries - hopefully that will get you going again :)